# How to make content fill the height of two column tcolorbox

Tags: spacing, tcolorbox, minipage

I have a two column tcolorbox and I am trying to make the content in the right column vertically expand to have similar height with the content of the left column. I tried adding `\par\vfill` or `\par\vspace*{\fill}` between the paragraphs and minipages of the right column. I also went through the manual and tried various combinations of the `text fill` `space=0.5` and `height fill` options to no avail. Actually, using the `height fill` gives the error "Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/height fill/' and I am going to ignore it."

I suppose it is something obvious but my limited experience with Latex doesn't help. Any suggestions?

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,caption,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=tcolorbox test,sidebyside,float]
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
    y = a x + b
\end{equation}
\lipsum[66]

\lipsum[75]

\tcblower

\lipsum[66]

\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
  \captionof{figure}{Praesent vitae lectus. Praesent neque justo, vehicula eget, interdum id.}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
  \captionof{figure}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae.}
\end{minipage}

\lipsum[75]

\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try adding an mbox after the vfill?

Comment: Do you mean something like \par\vfill\mbox{\lipsum} ? I just tried this and creates a single line of text extending beyond the borders of the tcolorbox to the end of the page.

Comment: If I understand correctly from the documentation, tcolorbox creates a minipage to put in the content of each column (in my scenario). I am mentioning this here because it might be useful information.

Comment: Some boxes kill the fills at the beginning or end. To prevent this, you can add an mbox on both sides. But this thing with outside of the colorbox is pretty strange.

Comment: You could put each column inside a parbox where you manually specify the height `\parbox[t][7in]{\linewidth}{ ... }`, and then `\vfill` inside should work, though that might be annoying. Right now your box contents are too long for a single page, however -- look at the poor page number.

Comment: Thanks @frabjous indeed surrounding the content with \parbox[t][7in]{\linewidth}{...} the \vfill works. Yes setting fixed height values is annoying but at least it is a first working option. Also, I was wondering why the whole box is visible even if it is longer than the printable area of the page, and I deliberately uploaded an example that is long just in case that it is informative. However, the height of the content in the right column is not expanding to fill the available height of the box even if I reduce the whole content so that the box is not that tall.

Comment: I really dislike using parbox here. Did you try `\vskip 0pt plus 1 filll\relax`? The filll beats the fills and it looks like there are some at the top and bottom.

Comment: I tried to redefine vfill and vskip, but that doesn't work either. Next step would be \show\tcblower as there is something going on inside it.